# How to get the RSA public-key from private-key Object in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, private-key, public-key

How to get the related public-key object `java.security.PublicKey` out of a private-key Object `java.security.PrivateKey` in the RSA cryptosystem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java is able to create a public key by using the modulus and exponent:

```
RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

So we need to extract these values out of the private key:

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = kf.getKeySpec(privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);
```

The `RSAPrivateKeySpec`-Object now contains the modulus we need, but the exponent is not the one we need for the public key.

For the public key the exponent is commonly at 65537:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537_(number)

Therefore we can now create the public key:

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = kf.getKeySpec(privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(priv.getModulus(), BigInteger.valueOf(65537));

PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

Comment: The public key exponent for RSA is not fixed at 65537, this is simply the most common value for it. Because the private key exponent is dependent on the public key exponent, this solution will not work for all situations.

Comment: @Syon you are right on this one, I corrected this, but using e≠65537 would reduce compatibility with existing hardware or software, and break conformance to some standards or prescriptions of security authorities therefore you wont find this normally. More informations here:
http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/impacts-of-not-using-rsa-exponent-of-65537

Comment: I agree with the post you cite iff you are creating a new public/private key-pair. Your question though is about deriving a public key from an existing private key. The only way you can do this is if you use the public key exponent that was used to create the original key-pair. Using 65537 in all situations will not work because that may not be the public key exponent. Compatibility with existing hardware or software has nothing to do with it.

Comment: What's wrong with just casting to `RSAPrivateKey` (after validating that it *is* an `RSAPrivateKey` of course)?

Answer (score 6):

You need to cast the private key into an RsaPrivateCrtKey. If the cast succeeds, you can extract the public key. If the cast fails, strictly speaking you don't have enough information.

```java
public static RSAPublicKey getPublicKeySpec(PrivateKey priv) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    RSAPrivateCrtKey rsaCrtKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) priv; // May throw a ClassCastException
    RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsaCrtKey.getModulus(), rsaCrtKey.getPublicExponent());
    return (RSAPublicKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);
}
```

If the cast fails, you can attempt to guess the public exponent and check your guess by using the standard RSA relation (x<sup>e</sup>)<sup>d</sup> = x mod N for all x. For your guess of e, try a few random x values in the equation and see if the relation always holds. This technique can only yield a probabilistic answer. For more details on finding the public exponent when it's not known, see [this answer on crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/91987/676).

Thanks to @SamGinrich for helpful suggestions.

Comment: The RSAPublicKey then comes from a KeyFactory as KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec);

Comment: think your answer was wise by not digging into details of that relation :) which is done here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/91987