# how I can make public key from private (ecdsa) in java without Bouncy Castle?

Tags: java, ecdsa

I have private key (ecdsa,secp256r1).

```
private final static String SHA = "SHA-256";
        private final static String MODE = "EC";
        private final static String PROV = "SunEC";
        private final static String ECC_ALGO = "secp256r1";

public static KeyPair eccKeyGen() {


                KeyPairGenerator kpg;
                KeyPair kp = null;
                try {
                        kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(MODE, PROV);
                        ECGenParameterSpec ecsp;
                        ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec(ECC_ALGO);
                        kpg.initialize(ecsp);
                        kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
                        return kp;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Key generation error.");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return kp;
```

How I can make public key from it in java without Bouncy Castle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the RSA public-key from private-key Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756420/how-to-get-the-rsa-public-key-from-private-key-object-in-java)

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your private key is in an OpenSSH format, you can use the `-y` option for `ssh-keygen`. For example, if your private is contained in `mykey`the following command will generate its public key

```
ssh-keygen -y -f mykey > mykey.pub
```

Comment: "Assuming your private key is in an OpenSSH format" How I can insert it in Java code?

Comment: Now that you added some code examples, I guess it is not an issue of having lost your public key. Are you asking if there are alternative JCE providers that can do the same as Bouncy Castle does?